# id3v2 info to text rescursive in all subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have problem: I creating text file info, with same name like mp3 with this:

```
for f in *.mp3; do id3v2 -l "$f" > "${f%mp3}txt"; done
```

It give me for every file.mp3 > file.txt with info about mp3 in curent directory.

How can I do same thing with subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy; just enable recursive globbing `**`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar ## enable recursive globbing operator **
for f in **/*.mp3; do id3v2 -l "${f}" > "${f%mp3}txt"; done
```